# iPhone App Crashing Upon Close/Reopen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

The application I have created works perfectly the first time around, but if I force close it via the bar at the bottom of the screen and open it back up, it crashes and won't reload. The only error I get is `Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGKILL".` and there is nothing in the log. This happens both in the iPhone simulator as well as my physical iPhone.

Edit: I have attached the debug log. Like I mentioned, nothing shows. This is the log AFTER the error is thrown and the application crashes.

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1703) (Thu May 26 17:11:52 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 835.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Anyone had an issue like this before?

Comment: So, what does the debugger or crash log say ?

Comment: When you close ur app from the home button the app will go into multitasking mode. you can disable this by making this : in ur appdelegate .h BOOL multitasking; .m - (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application { if(!multitasking) { exit(0); return; } }

Comment: Nothing. I mentioned that in the original post.

Comment: I disabled multitasking in the info.plist and when I tried the same process again it displayed an error in the debug output. I fixed the error and now it works as intended. Now I can close and reopen the application via the bar at the bottom with no problem whatsoever. 

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If you close your app through the multitasking bar, you need to restart the debugging process over. I've seen this in development several times. This will not negatively impact your app once it has shipped. This happens because the debugger was connected to the app when it terminated. Your users aren't debugging your app so they won't have this issue.

Comment: It has never done this before neither in the simulator nor on my iPhone.

Comment: Is this your first "multitasking aware" app?  Like I said, this is completely normal and I've seen this in development several times. This will not negatively impact your app once it has shipped.

Comment: No it is not. Also, this app has been in development for quite some time and I have tried the same process of closing/reopen and it has always come up fine.

Comment: If I do it on the iPhone it just hangs on the loading screen, then turns black after a minute or so.

Comment: I disabled multitasking in the info.plist and when I tried the same process again it displayed an error in the debug output. I fixed the error and now it works as intended. Now I can close and reopen the application via the bar at the bottom with no problem whatsoever. 

Thanks for the help though!